# Need a refresher don't know where to start.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm currently reading a book on programming. An example gives me a (correct me if I'm wrong) series:
$$
  X + \frac{X}{2} + \frac{X}{4} + \frac{X}{8} + \dotsb + 1
$$
The answer given is roughly: $2X$

It's been a while since I've touched any type of calculus so I have no clue where to start.

Comment: It is a geometric series!

Comment: Is there a +1 in the end?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Yes, apologies for the formatting.

Comment: But then, the answer should be $2X + 1$. This is because the series $X + \dfrac{X}{2} + \dfrac{X}{4} + \cdots$ converges to $2X$. And then there is a $+1$ at the end which makes the final answer $2X + 1$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Ah, I see. Thank you. I guess I have to look into geometric series again.

Comment: What do you mean by "roughly" $2x$?

Comment: @littleO In the context of the programming book, the constant gets omitted. It's on the subject of BigO notation. It's just been awhile since I had to deal with series that it's all kind of blurry to me now.

Comment: Here's a trick for summing an infinite geometric series. Let $S = 1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + \cdots$, where $|r| < 1$. Notice that $1 + rS = S$. (That is a very neat observation). We can now solve for $S$ using algebra to discover that $S = 1/(1 - r)$. That is a nice formula. In the special case that $r = 1/2$, we have $S = 1/(1/2) = 2$.

Comment: @littleO Thank you for clearing my mind a bit. One thing, I'm a bit confused with the 1 + rS = S observation. I understand that's the pattern of the series, but where does the S in rS come from?

Comment: Starting from $S=1+r+r^2+r^3+\cdots$, multiply both sides by $r$ to obtain $rS = r+ r^2 + r^3+\cdots$. Then add $1$ to both sides of the equation, which gives us $1+rS = 1+r+r^2+r^3+\cdots$. But the quantity on the right is just $S$! (Very neat how that worked out.) So we have discovered that $1+rS=S$.

Comment: @littleO Ohhh, clever. Thank you so much, did some more searching and I finally understand. Again, you and everyone here were big help.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Toboggan and welcome to MSE. As it has been said in the comments, what you wrote looks like a geometric series. I assume that what you are trying to compute is
$$1+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{X}{2^i}$$
for $X\neq 0$ (otherwise it is trivial).

The idea of how to compute it relies on the following facts:

1. $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}X/2^i=\lim_{t\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{t}X/2^i=X\cdot\left(\lim_{t\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{t}2^{-i}\right)$;
2. Write $S_t$ for $\sum_{i=0}^{t}2^{-i}$, then $$\frac{1}{2^{t+1}}+S_t=S_{t+1}=1+\frac{1}{2}S_t$$ and so $$S_t = \frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{t+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}.$$
   Now you should be able to finish by your own.